# Abnormal Behavior of the function "localtime" in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, embedded-linux

I used the function `localtime` twice by putting in the same argument.
However, I may get different results. The latter one may have one second more. The code is below.

```
ptCurrentTime = localtime(&(t_TriggerTime));
ptCurrentTime = localtime(&(t_TriggerTime));
```

I printed out the results. The first one may be like `2015-11-07 22:19:56.123` and the second one may be like `2015-11-07 22:19:57.123`.
Is that normal?

Comment: Please post the code that printed the time.

Comment: The standard versions of `localtime()` have no idea about fractions of a second.  No, it isn't normal to see the same value printed as two different values.  However, we'd need to see more code to be able to guess what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not normal for that sort of change to happen. You should generally only get a different value if:

- `t_TriggerTime` changes; or
- if your timezone changes (and timezones rarely shift by a second, they tend to mostly prefer hourly or half-hourly jumps); or
- there's a serious bug in your `localtime()` function; or
- you're running multiple threads and the shared state is being changed.

That last point bears looking into. If some other thread of execution is calling the time functions as well, `localtime()` often returns the address of an internal object which can be modified without you being aware.

If it turns out this is the problem, multi-threaded systems may provide a thread-safe variant that uses an object you *provide* rather than a shared internal one. For example,

```
struct tm tms;
struct tm *ptms = localtime_r (&t_TriggerTime, &tms);
// ptms is now &tms, so use ptms->X (or tms.X).
```

However, I'd also be examining your printing code very thoroughly, the standard `struct tm` has no concept of sub-second resolution so I've no idea where your `.123` is coming from.

Comment: Hi Paxdiablo,

You are right. The struct has no concept of sub-second resolution. That is added by myself. 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My program is multi-thread. So...you mean the problem may happen at the situation that other thread calls localtime just the same time when I call it the second time?

Comment: @Ryan, yes, I'd look into `localtime_r()` as an option. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very helpful!